# How to create a BEFORE INSERT Trigger

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger and getting errors that I don't understand.

The MySQL to create the trigger looks like this:

```sql
CREATE  TRIGGER `GetPolyLinkID` BEFORE INSERT ON `TableA` 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TableB () VALUES ();
    NEW.PolyLinkID = last_insert_id();
END
```

The error I'm getting is

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 1

Answer (score 1):

You forgot `SET` ... begore `NEW.PolyLinkID = last_insert_id();`

And

For creating complex trigger , you must use the `delimiter` keyword .

This is a example from  rom https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/trigger-syntax.html .

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER upd_check BEFORE UPDATE ON account
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF NEW.amount < 0 THEN
       SET NEW.amount = 0;
   ELSEIF NEW.amount > 100 THEN
        SET NEW.amount = 100;
   END IF;
END;
//
delimiter ;
```

Screen shot with sequel pro

[image: example with SEQUEL PRO]

Comment: Tried that.  I now get "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.PolyLinkID = last_insert_id();END' at line 5"

Comment: I don;t think the delimiter is needed unless you are using non-DDL statements such as IF

Comment: the delimter is needed when you used `;`   in the procedure/trigger

Comment: The delimiter is only needed when using the mysql command line interface, I'm using Sequel Pro.  IN any case, I still get an error when trying to use Deleimiter.

Comment: OK, I think you're missing the point.  Whether I use a delimiter or not, I'm getting an SQL error.